# C++ memory allocation for windows

Tags: c++, windows

So I'm reading Windows via c/c++ fifth edition which was released before c11 so lacks some of the newer data types and methods, but was touted to be a great book on Windows.

I am just learning Windows development and c++ and when I posted questions related to file operations with code samples from the book, I got feedback that allocating buffers with the malloc function is not a good practice anymore as it requires freeing up the memroy. I should use vectors or strings instead.

That is ok. But what is the case with Windows's own data types? Here is a code sample from the book:

```
//initialization omitted
BOOL bResult = GetLogicalProcessorInformation(pBuffer, &dwSize);
if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
_tprintf(TEXT("Impossible to get processor information\n"));
return;
}
pBuffer = (PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION)malloc(dwSize);
bResult = GetLogicalProcessorInformation(pBuffer, &dwSize);
```

Is there a better solution for this type of query than using malloc to allocate the proper amount of memory?

Or is declaring a vector of type PROCESOR INFORMATION STRUCTRUE the way to go?

Comment: Vectors work perfectly fine.

Comment: Wha's the type of `bBuffer`?

Comment: it is PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION

Comment: That is clearly a C book you've gotten your hands on. If it were a C++ book, it would *at a minimum* allocate memory with the `new` operator. Better yet, it would use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: @Sesertin: The unfortunate answer is that there is no nice way of doing this; you have to allocate the buffer as a byte array, re-allocate it if it's too small, and perform the casting yourself.

Comment: @CodyGray, `std::array` requires knowledge of array size at compile time. That's not the case here as `GetLogicalProcessorInformation` populates an array whose size is impossible to know beforehand.

Comment: Yes, hence the *or*. It was a general answer to the question, not a specific working implementation. (That should have been obvious from the fact that I posted it as a *comment*, rather than an answer.) In some cases, you'll need `std::vector`. In other cases, when you know the size at compile time, you should use `std::array`. The C++ book should cover this, too.  @duncan

Answer (score 1):

The win32 api is sometimes a pain to use, but you could allways use the raw bytes in a `std::vector<char>` as a `SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION`:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION));
size_t buffersize = buffer.size();

SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION *ptr 
   = (SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION *)&(buffer[0]);

BOOL bResult = GetLogicalProcessorInformation(ptr, &buffersize);
if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
  {
    buffer.resize(buffersize);
    ptr = (SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION *)&(buffer[0]);
    bResult = GetLogicalProcessorInformation(ptr, &buffersize);
  }
```

Just be avare that the value of `&(buffer[0])` may change after `buffer.resize(...);`
Other than that, I normally don't use the win32 api, so any bugs concerning how to call win32, you have to fix yourself

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194(v=vs.85).aspx) and you will see that buffer should be *"A pointer to a buffer that receives an array of SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION structures. If the function fails, the contents of this buffer are undefined."* So Zdeslav Vojkovic's answer will not work here (as Raymond Chen has pointed out). You *could* use `std::vector<SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION>` in this case and then just call 'resize' with `dwSize / sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION)` as the argument. This would look something like:

```
using SLPI = SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION;
std::vector<SLPI> slpi;
DWORD dwSize = 0;

if (!GetLogicalProcessorInformation(slpi.data(), &dwSize))
{
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) { /* error handling */ }

    // Not really necessary, but good to make sure
    assert(dwSize % sizeof(SLPI) == 0);

    slpi.resize(dwSize / sizeof(SLPI));
    if (!GetLogicalProcessorInformation(slpi.data(), &dwSize)) { /* error handling */ }
}
```

Personally, I'd prefer to wrap the above into a function and just return `slpi` so you don't need to go through this entire shenanigans every time you wish to make a call to `GetLogicalProcessorInformation`.

Comment: You are right, of course. I have completely missed the specific issues with SLPI structure, and focused on generally allocating a Win API structure, but it's broken in this case. I have deleted the answer - no point confusing people.